# Firebase Signup - Async function not working

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am basically trying to do this:

- Call SignUpService2 and get authData from firebase.
- I want to handle    the error in the top level function.

The problem is my top level function will return **Undefined**. The top level console log inside the `then` executes earlier than the target function. Even when there is error in the target function, the top level function still executes code inside the "then" . I was expecting to catch the error from target function within the `catch` code in the Top Level. What am I doing wrong?

```js
//TOP LEVEL 
// Call function here
SignUpService2(values.email, values.password)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('DEBUG:: Top Level  -> result', result)

        authContext.signUp() // dispatch
        props.navigation.navigate('AfterSignup', 'User Created Successfully')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        const resMessage =
          (err.response && err.response.data && err.response.data.message) ||
          err.message ||
          err.toString()
        setserverErrMessage(resMessage)
        actions.setSubmitting(false)
      })
  }
  
  
  
  
  //TARGET 
  // Define function here
  const SignUpService2 = async (email, password) => {
  auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((authData) => {
      console.log('DEBUG:: authData', authData)


      const usersData = {}

      usersData.displayName = authData.user.displayName 
      usersData.email = email.toLowerCase()
      usersData.aboutme = ''

      database()
        .ref('users/' + authData.user.uid)
        .set(usersData)
        .then((result) => {
          return 'User Created Successfully (FS Service)'
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('DEBUG:: err', err)
          return 'Error: Some error occured while saving profile  in database (FS Service)'
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('DEBUG:: Target  err', err)
      return err
    })
```

This is the logs when i run the code.

```
 LOG  DEBUG:: Top Level -> result undefined
 LOG  DEBUG:: Target  err [Error: [auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account.]
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have defined the `SignUpService2` as an `async` function but you are not returning a Promise from that function

just add return before the `auth()` function:

```
const SignUpService2 = async (email, password) => {
return auth()
   .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then((authData) => {
     console.log('DEBUG:: authData', authData)


  const usersData = {}

  usersData.displayName = authData.user.displayName 
  usersData.email = email.toLowerCase()
  usersData.aboutme = ''

  database()
    .ref('users/' + authData.user.uid)
    .set(usersData)
    .then((result) => {
      return 'User Created Successfully (FS Service)'
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('DEBUG:: err', err)
      return 'Error: Some error occured while saving profile  in database (FS Service)'
    })
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('DEBUG:: Target  err', err)
  return err
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that works. I wind up doing like this. One more question. Will the error from the code inside the `then` `i.e database().ref('users/' + authData.user.uid)` also returned to the top level function?

Also, is there a way for me to return the `authData` in the Top level function?
Right now even with this change, I get **Undefined** when the Target Function is a success.

```
DEBUG:: handleSubmit -> result undefined
```

```js
const SignUpService2 = async (email, password) => {
  return auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((authData) => {
      console.log('DEBUG:: authData', authData)
      console.log('DEBUG:: authData22222222222', authData.user.uid)

      const usersData = {}

      usersData.displayName = authData.user.displayName // ? Not needed since at this point Display name is not set yet
      usersData.email = email.toLowerCase()
      usersData.aboutme = '' // ? Not needed since at this point Display name is not set yet

      database()
        .ref('users/' + authData.user.uid)
        .set(usersData)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log('DEBUG:: result', result)
        })
      
    })
```